# Place a subquery in the column list (Hive)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My DB - Hadoop, Hive
I have tried to run a query with subquery on the select and it did not run. Please find the query below

Thanks for helping

```
select 
to_date(timestamp) as date,
count(*),
(select count(*) from table1 where to_date(timestamp)=current_date() and arrivaltime IS null) as count_null
FROM table1
WHERE to_date(ingest_timestamp) =current_date()
GROUP BY date, count_null
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'it did not run'?

Comment: The query above didn't run, it got an error when I was trying to run it and I don't know why.

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

convert the sub query to a case when. also you can not group by `count_null` column. if you really need to group by `count_null` then built a query on top of this query. Below SQL will return `total_count`, `count_null`, and `count_not_null`

```
select 
to_date(timestamp) as date,
count(*) total_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 1 else 0 END) as count_null,
SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 0 else 1 END) as count_not_null,
SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 0 else 1 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 1 else 0 END)
as diff_not_null_and_null
FROM 
table1 
WHERE to_date(timestamp)=current_date
GROUP BY to_date(timestamp)
```

Example -
Lets assume  you have data like this -

```
Flightid, timestamp, arrivaltime 
Flight1, 2021-01-29,2021-01-29 10:00:00  
Flight2, 2021-01-29,
Flight4, 2021-01-29,2021-01-29 11:00:00 
Flight5, 2021-01-29,2021-01-29 10:30:00 
Flight9, 2021-01-29,
```

Result will be -

```
timestamp,  total_count, count_null, count_not_null, diff_not_null_and_null
2021-01-29, 5,           2,          3,              1
```

In above SQL i calculated three attributes -

1. SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 1 else 0 END) - when the arrivaltime is null then its going to assign value of 1 to that row. now if you sum them, you will get total count when arrival time is null. in above example its 2.
2. SUM(CASE WHEN arrivaltime IS null then 0 else 1 END) - opposite to above logic, we assign 1 when arrivaltime is not null. Then sum will result count of all not null rows. in above example its 3.
3. then the difference between 2 and 1. in above example its 3-2 =1.

Comment: Thanks for that, but what I am trying to achieve is slightly different. I want to count the total records for each day and to split this total count into 2 parts - 1) when arrivaltime is null, so count only the null. 2) when arrivaltime is not null, so count only the not null recodes.

Comment: you can use above sql

Comment: yes that can be achieved with case statement

Comment: Thanks guys, that's brilliant !

Comment: Quick question regarding this, how could I create a difference between  (count_not_null, count_null ). I have tried to do it like (count_not_null-count_null as difference) and it didn't work

Comment: you can use sql in answer.. same sql can be used.

Comment: Hey@KoushikRoy would you be able to explain that in more detail ? I'm afraid that I didn't get you right